# Appium automation is not able to find elementByAccessibilityId of reusableTableHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, automation, appium

The actual scenario is like this, I have tableView with multiple sections, and using reusableTableHeaderFooterView. The reusable view has multiple elements inside it. ie. Label, Button etc.

[image: Custom Header View] [image: Custme Header View XIB]

I am calling configure method inside viewForHeaderInSection after dequeuing headerView and setting accessibilities in configure a method as per below code.

**In ViewController**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

      let customHeader:CustomHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomHeader") as! CustomHeader
      customHeader.configureWith(section: section)

      return customHeader

    }
```

**CustomHeaderView**

```
class CustomHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

      @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var seeAllButton: UIButton!

      override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
      }

      func configureWith(section:Int){

        titleLabel.text = "Section \(section)"

        self.isAccessibilityElement = false
        titleLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
        seeAllButton.isAccessibilityElement = true

        self.accessibilityElements = [titleLabel, seeAllButton]
        titleLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "Section Header- \(section)"
        seeAllButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "Section Button- \(section)"

      }
    }
```

In end, I am not able to access elements of some of the header views. It works fine with header views which are already displayed on the screen when screen loads, but not for the sections which display after scrolling.

In appium Desktop application, I am not able to select element inside headerView as follow. Even I can not find it after searching element by accessibilityId.

** Expected : ** Working properly for section 3

[image]

** Unexpected ** Not working for section 4

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did u find any solution for that?

Comment: Yes but not with the same code, I have changed my implementation to static headers instead of reusable header views and it worked for me. @prasad

Answer (score 0):

Does the app is made in Hybrid app i prefer to use xpath insted of accessibility id, developer needs to add the attribute for accessibility id.

Comment: No, it isn't a hybrid app, It's native iOS application. And I have provided accessibility ids for all those elements.